# ConnectWise SDK, bad request when creating products

Tags: c#, api, sdk, bad-request

I am trying to work with the ConnectWise SDK to create tickets and products in ConnectWise Manage.
I have managed to get the connection to work and I can create tickets without a problem, but I keep getting a "400 - Bad Request" when I try to create a product.

I am using C# in Visual Studio.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
private static async Task TestPost()
{
    //Create the client
    var client = getApiClient();



    //Get a ticket to duplicate
    var ticketsApi = new TicketsApi(client);
    var getResponse = await ticketsApi.GetTicketByIdAsync(55482);
    var ticket = await getResponse.GetResultAsync<Ticket>();                //I get the correct ticket here

    //Create the duplicate ticket
    var createResponseTicket = await ticketsApi.CreateTicketAsync(ticket);  //This works without error
    var newTicket = await createResponseTicket.GetResultAsync<Ticket>();
    Console.WriteLine("Ticket ID: " + newTicket.Id);



    //Get a product to duplicate
    var productsApi = new ProductsItemApi(client);
    var response = await productsApi.GetProductByIdAsync(1);
    var product = await response.GetResultAsync<ProductItem>();             //I get the correct product here

    //Create the duplicate product
    var createResponseProduct = await productsApi.CreateProductAsync(product);  //Here I get a "400 - Bad Request" error
    var newProduct = await createResponseProduct.GetResultAsync<ProductItem>();
    Console.WriteLine("Product ID: " + newProduct.Id);
}
```